# Far Future Expire Headers

Tags: headers, cache-control

Do you use these? If so, what strategies do you have for managing changes to the files?

http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/05/high_performanc_2.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using a small script combined with a .htaccess rule. Basically, the script takes the file modification timestamp and adds it to it's name (in the web page), while the .htaccess rule redirects the file with the timestamp in the name to the corresponding file from the hdd.

I took this from the Particletree blog, here: http://particletree.com/notebook/automatically-version-your-css-and-javascript-files/

It works perfectly for me.

Comment: That's really cool.  You could do the same thing with SVN revision number or some similar tag if the timestamp isn't reliable in your deployment system.  There is some overhead with all the extra (internal) requests though.